# How can I set a form field as invalid?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular5

I want to validate the length of a field, after removing it's mask. I'm using https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask, and because of that, I can't just use the property "minLength". With the mask that doesn't work. Always has the size expected, even the user just typed one character. Therefore, the need of calling a method in "ngModelChange", clear the mask, and then see the length of the text.

So the question is, how can I set this form field as invalid, if it fails my method validation?

```js
checkDigitosCPF() {
  const qtdDigitos = _.replace(this.advogado.cpf, /\D/g, '').length;
  this.isCPFNotOk = _.isEqual(qtdDigitos, 11);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="field_cpf">CPF</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpf" id="field_cpf" [(ngModel)]="advogado.cpf" required [textMask]="{mask: cpfMask}" (ngModelChange)="checkDigitosCPF()" minlength="11" />
  <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.cpf?.dirty && editForm.controls.cpf?.invalid)">
    <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!editForm.controls.cpf?.errors?.required" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.required">
      This field is required.
    </small>
    <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="isCPFNotOk">
      Esse campo deve ter no min&iacute;mo 11 car&aacute;cteres.
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question. I got the desired behavior by creating a custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

In the **component** the validator method should look like this:

```
// this function should be triggered each time the value change or the form submit

validateField(form): void {
    if (conditionOfError) {
        form.controls.yourFieldName.setErrors({'customLengthError': true})
    } else {
        form.controls.yourFieldName.updateValueAndValidity()
    }
}
```

In the **form html** error list:

```
<small *ngIf="yourFieldName?.errors?.customLengthError">
    The error text.
</small>
```